# Oracle SQL to_date function not working on concatenated strings

Tags: sql, oracle

I've been looking for a reason that this isn't working for quite some time.  I'm concatenating two fields and attempting to run some date comparisons but it throws the error ORA-01843: not a valid month.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT
   sm.semester_date || cp.start_year AS effective
FROM
   database.table cp,
   database.table2 sm
WHERE   cp.semesters_id = sm.semesters_id 
AND  to_date(sm.semester_date || cp.start_year, 'MM/DD/YYYY') >= to_date('06/01/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

It runs fine as long as I don't add that AND statement at the end.  But I need to filter the dataset.

When you run it without the filter it returns 08/15/2010 etc.

I forgot to add the mask originally when I posted this, I've corrected that. However, it still returns this error  ORA-01840: input value not long enough for date format.

**EDIT  SOLUTION FOUND:**
Firstly, thanks to everyone for helping me with this, you guys are great.  Secondly, my error was being caused by a course without a start year.  Very frustrating since that shouldn't be able to happen.  Because the concatenated item had no year on it, it was throwing the error.  I only found this because you guys helped me fix my code up.  Thank you.

Comment: what is "sm.semester_date || cp.start_year" returning? Have you ensured it's in the 'MM/DD/YYYY' format?

Answer (score 4):

Try adding a separator between date and year:

```
SELECT
   sm.semester_date || '/' || cp.start_year AS effective
FROM
   database.table cp,
   database.table2 sm
WHERE   cp.semesters_id = sm.semesters_id 
AND  to_date(sm.semester_date || '/' || cp.start_year) >= to_date('06/01/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY')
```

If you run the query without the filter, what does it return?

Comment: @Justin: query first, explanations later!

Comment: If I run it without the filter it returns 8/10/2008 etc.

Comment: This solution may work, but I would recommend specifying the date format explicitly so you're not relying on the default.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your default date format does not match the format of the string that you are passing to TO_DATE.  Add a format string as a second parameter to the call (as you've done for the second call) to specify what the format of the concatenated string is.

Answer (score 1):

Is the `SEMESTER_DATE` column a VARCHAR2?  And if so, is it a string in the format 'MM/DD/'?  Or just 'MM/DD'?

As lweller points out, the first TO_DATE is also missing the format mask which would be a problem if your session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` is anything other than 'MM/DD/YYYY'.

Assuming `SEMESTER_DATE` is a VARCHAR2 in the format 'MM/DD', I suspect you want

```
AND to_date( sm.semester_date || '/' || cp.start_year, 'MM/DD/YYYY' ) >= 
      to_date( '06/01/2011', 'MM/DD/YYYY' )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first TO_DATE() relies in the system's default format. Provide a second argument with a proper format string, such as `'MM/DD/YYYY'`. Please compare:

```
SELECT SEMESTER_DATE || START_YEAR AS BARE_STRING, TO_DATE(SEMESTER_DATE || START_YEAR) AS CASTED_TO_DATE
FROM (
    SELECT '12/31' AS SEMESTER_DATE, 2010 AS START_YEAR
    FROM DUAL
);

SELECT SEMESTER_DATE || START_YEAR AS BARE_STRING, TO_DATE(SEMESTER_DATE || START_YEAR, 'MM/DD/YYYY') AS CASTED_TO_DATE
FROM (
    SELECT '12/31' AS SEMESTER_DATE, 2010 AS START_YEAR
    FROM DUAL
);
```